# Swift - How to make one action if 2 buttons are pressed?

Tags: xcode, swift

In `main.storyboard`, I have a gun button and a shield button. Say both buttons are clicked at the same time (not exactly the same time but you know what I mean).

How do I make one action after both buttons are clicked? like in this case if gun and shield were clicked I want to make a label say defended. pretty much what I am asking for is how I would could that in the view controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.  Connect both buttons to each `IBAction`, and make sure that `onButtonDown:` is trigger by the control event `.TouchDownInside`, and that `onButtonUp:` is trigger by both `.TouchUpInside` and `.TouchDragExit`.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var buttonsPressed: [UIButton] = []

    // Triggered by .TouchDownInside
    @IBAction func onButtonDown( sender: UIButton ) {
        self.buttonsPressed.append( sender )

        if self.buttonsPressed.count == 2 {
            // Both buttons are pressed
        }
    }

    // Triggered by .TouchUpInside and .TouchDragExit
    @IBAction func onButtonUp( sender: UIButton ) {
        for i in 0..<self.buttonsPressed.count {
            if self.buttonsPressed[i] == sender {
                self.buttonsPressed.removeAtIndex( i )
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Add that `break` statement in the loop to prevent crashing

Comment: I just ran in to a new problem with this code. When I run on my iPhone, the app immediately  crashes right after my labels text change when you click both buttons. In Xcode it says "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Comment: My apologies!  Add that `break`  in there and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a statement in each buttons logic. For example in the shield button I would add something like "if gun is active display label" and also add a similar statement to the gun logic "if shield is active display label". You may need to use a value specific to your shield or gun action, Like "if shield value == 50". You could go one step further if you plan on using multiple combinations and create a common action that each if statement will then call for you.